# Parallel requests to update the same field in ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My web application is developed using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` 2.2.0 . In a `PUT` request, I update a column in the database. The code below is my demonstration:

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/{id}/increment/{increment}")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutIncrement([FromRoute] int id, [FromRoute] float increment)
{
    Model m = _context.Model
                      .Where(f => f.Id == id)
                      .SingleOrDefault();

    m.Value += increment;

    _context.Entry(m).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(m);
}
```

Then I call this same requests (https://localhost/api/1/increment/1) 10 times in parallel with 7 CPUs. I expect the value equal to 10. However, the actual value in the database is much less than 10 (about 2-4). How should I process the request one by one in the ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You can implement `Optimistic Concurrency` --- > *Optimistic concurrency assumes that the update being made will be accepted, but prior to the change being made in the database, the original values of the record are compared to the existing row in the database and if any changes are detected, a concurrency exception is raised.*

Comment: If your requests are coming at a very high volume you should use in-memory db or cachce provide like redis. Optimistic concurrency won't solve the issue of updating the field it will throw an exception if the matching criteria don't meat.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have any example I can use?

Comment: @Bangyou you can Google there are a lot of resources out there. This [link](https://garywoodfine.com/why-when-and-how-to-use-redis-in-asp-net-mvc-core/) might help you get starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Optimistic Concurrency

> Optimistic Concurrency assumes that the update being made will be accepted, but prior to the change being made in the database, the original values of the record are compared to the existing row in the database and if any changes are detected, a concurrency exception is raised.

It can be enabled by adding a property `RowVersion` as  shown below

```
public class Model
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     ........ // Other Properties
     public int Value {get; set;} 

     [TimeStamp]
     public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

The `RowVersion` column will be configured as a database type that provides automatic row-versioning.

Now, you can wrap the `SaveChangesAsync` method in `try-catch` to handle the optimistic concurrency issues. Check [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) for more details.

```
try
{
    // business logic
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    // Other business logic
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    // your logic to handle optimistic concurrency.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As @MuhammadHannan  mentioned, Optimistic concurrency cannot totally solve my situation as it is only throw an exception, but cannot lock the field and update.

Comment: @Bangyou - in exception block you should read the record again and try saving after business model update. Please check the link i’ve already Posted in my answer.

Comment: You can also look for use of **pessimistic concurrency** which locks the row; However is not recommended in distributed services..